# Joomla 3.2 - view $this->get('Form') returns false and then returns the form

Tags: php, joomla, joomla3.2

I have a strange problem with Joomla 3.2.

I'm following this master-detail tutorial (http://library.logicsistemi.it/en/joomla/creating-a-mvc-master-detail-interface-in-joomla-2-5/47-create-a-mvc-master-detail-interface-in-joomla-2-5-part-1) written for Joomla 2.5. It's pretty straight-forward, but I have a really annoying problem: In the view, when I call to $this->get('Form') it returns false. If I call $this->get('Form'), it returns the form!

I undertand that this isn't the correct behavior, because if then I call to $form->getFieldset() I get an empty array...

My code:

views/document/view.html.php:

```
defined('_JEXEC') or die('Restricted access');

jimport('joomla.application.component.view');

class MasterDetailViewDocument extends JViewLegacy
{
    function display($tpl = null)
    {
//      $form = $this->get('Form');
        $item = $this->get('Item');
        $form = $this->get('Form');
//die(var_dump($item));
    die(var_dump($form));
        $isNew = ($item->id < 1);
    }
}
```

models/forms/document.php:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<form>
    <fieldset>
        <field name="id" type="hidden" />
        <field name="fk_master" type="hidden" />
        <field name="name" type="text" label="Description" size="40" class="inputbox" />
        <field name="filename" type="media" directory="attachments" />
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Anyone knows what I'm doing wrong? Why I have to call two times to $this->get('Form')? Why $form->getFieldSet() returns an empty array?

Answer (score 2):

I've found the problem: my models/forms/document.php name is incorrect. It must be models/forms/document.xml.

After changing the name, all is working correctly.